# Train to extract href attribute with scrapely

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapely

I am using [Scrapely](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely) to extract data fields from HTML. Using `train` then `scrape` per the doc fails to extract the `href` attribute from links. Is there a way to extract href attributes in a similar manner to extracting text from elements?

```
from scrapely import Scraper
s = Scraper()

url1 = 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/w3lib/1.1'
data = {'vers_url': 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/w3lib/1.14.2'}
s.train(url1, data)

url2 = 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/1.3'
print(s.scrape(url2)) 
# Prints {u'vers_url': [u'\n<span>1.10a1</span>\n']}], should print a url
```

In the training example above, the url given is a unique `href` attribute of an `a` tag on that page so I would expect the algorithm would be able to learn to find it.

Comment: please provide code snippets.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I've added some example code.